# Angularjs 4 - Global service value in HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-service, angular-services

In Angular < 1 versions, I used to access the $rootScope variables in HTML like

Working
    JS
    $rootScope.sports.type = "Cricket";

and

```
HTML 
<div> {{sports.type}} </div>
```

Current code which is Not working - Angularjs 4
Service TS

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class GlobalModelProvider {
  sportsType: string;
  constructor() { 
  }
```

Home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { GlobalModelProvider } from "../../providers/global-model/global-model";

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
})
export class HomePage {
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: 
             NavParams, public globalModel:GlobalModelProvider) {
         this.globalModel.sportType = "Cricket";
    }
}
```

and

```
Home.html
<ion-content>
    <div>
        Welcome to {{globalModel.sportType}} section
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

What is the equivalent in AngularJS 4 ? I have tried creating a Global service in JS and I was able to access those global service values in Javascript, but when it comes to HTML it doesn't work.

Comment: In the code behind for the page, the .ts file, you need to set a variable to be equal to the value coming from the service. You then access that variable in the html, the same way you would a value declared in the ts. Is this what you are doing and it isn't working? Post up your code and we can help more.

Comment: @Steve. please find the updated question

Answer (score 0):

OK, you're setting the value with that code. But not holding it as a value in the ts file. You need to do this:

```
this.sportType = "Cricket";
this.globalModel.sportType = this.sportType;
```

And in the HTML:

```
{{sportType}}
```

And to retrieve a value:

```
this.sportType = this.globalModel.sportType;
```

Comment: Yeah, this will work because you will use a local variable in that particular component to display it in the HTML. But what I was looking for something like $rootScope stuff. I will assign a value in different controller and I can use it in any HTML.

Comment: This tutorial from the Angular docs seems to show that it can be done in a way you're after (without setting the service return into a variable): https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4. Skip to the mesages service demo half way down.